# Skip a Static method call in using mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I've a method in my main class which calls webservice. I want to skip that method calling, how can I do it in mockito. code is as below

```
MainCLass{

int main(){
    // I want to skip this method getting called
    MyClass.callWebservice();
}
}
```

Comment: You can't refactor the source code of the `MainClass` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a static call which can't be mocked just by using Mockito. But you can do this with [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) for example. It is a bit complex, you find an example here: [MockStatic](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use PowerMock, you could do the following:

- Extract the webservice call into an own method.
- Extend your MainClass and override this method or use a spy and stub the method.

But for sure it would be a valid argument if you wouldn't want to change your productive code only for this test.